# Relation of a Tensor in Neuronal Network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, tensor

So I read a lot about Tensors. I kind of understand the concept enough for my purpose. But I can't find any information about how they are used exactly in a NN. For example I use Tensorflow to build a NN to classify images. The only information I have: Layers are build with Tensors.
Now my problem: As I understand Neuronal Networks are constructed with Neurons. And a layer in it is built with many Neurons.

- Are Neurons and Tensors equivalent in Tensorflow?
- Are Tensors the input of Neurons?
- How do they work together?

My question may sound trivial. But I can't find any information about it. They rather talk about Tensors **or** Neurons. But not how they are used together in a Neuronal Network with Tensorflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, here are some relevant definitions:

> Neural Networks are modeled as collections of neurons that are
> connected in an acyclic graph. In other words, the outputs of some
> neurons can become inputs to other neurons. [...] Neural Network models are often organized  into distinct layers of neurons ([cs231n](https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/)).

> Graphs are data structures that contain a set of tf.Operation objects,
> which represent units of computation; and tf.Tensor objects, which
> represent the units of data that flow between operations ([Tensorflow intro to graphs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs)).

Now to the questions:

> Are Neurons and Tensors equivalent in Tensorflow?

No. Tensors are units of data. Artificial neurons are functions. Such functions can be implemented with tf.Operations and process the data stored in tensors.

> Are Tensors the input of Neurons?

For example, yes. Neurons can store inputs or outputs of neurons.

Hope that helps. I am happy to expand the answer with more details.

Comment: So when I understand your answer correctly. In Tensorflow I build a Neuronal Network with multiple Neurons in each layer. And the input and output of those neurons are the tensors. And Tensors are just a form of data. Is that correct?

Comment: For the sake of correctness, I think it is important to distinguish different conceptual levels here. "Implementation level": in Tensorflow you build computational graphs, with the nodes of the graph being operations and tensors with data flowing between the nodes. "Computational/mathematical level": these graphs can represent neural networks with the groups of operations corresponding to the individual neurons.

Comment: Well thank you. It is confusing as we talk about a neuronal network with neurons, but tensorflow is doing a different approach.